# How to generate a random URL for a random generated page

Tags: javascript, url, cookies, random, generator

**Some context on what I want to achieve**
My page is generating random content on refresh by using javascript's math.random.
The content will get a lot of different variables including a ton of arrays.
I need to generate an URL or a permalink for the content generated. Like an ID or hash.

**First option**
Generate the URL first as a seed then generate the content afterwards.

**Section option**
Generate the page content then get a permalink for the generated content.
Maybe use the arrays in the URL? example.com/ItemItem5Item4Item18

With my lack of knowledge in JavaScript I need more explanation and elaboration. If you could show me some resources or a sample code it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific.  As written, it's not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah this is really hard to explain but I edited it now.

Comment: If the user refreshes, why wouldn't they see the same content? This seems contrary to your requirement that the URL for the content be "permanent."

Comment: The point of the website is refreshing it and generate random content. I just need to get an URL for the generated content.

Comment: If the content is randomly-generated server-side then you can seed whatever PRNG you're using with the value in the URI.  If there is no value, generate a random seed, build the URI, then seed the PRNG and generate the page as usual.

Comment: If you're wanting to generate on the client-side using JavaScript, you will have to write your own (or use a third-party) PRNG instead of relying on Math.random, because (a) Math.random does not accept developer-specified seeds and (b) browsers are not required to implement the same PRNG algorithm.

Comment: I have no experience in PRNG either. That's why I'm asking. I also updated the question again.